# workspace-based application insight pricing calculator

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitor

I am planning to use the Azure Monitor service and specifically Workspace-based Application Insights for the client's project.

Before I purpose/implement Workspace-based Application Insights, I need to share the estimated cost with the client so I checked the [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/) however in Azure Pricing Calculator for Azure Monitor service they have mentioned ONLY Classic Application Insights and I am interested in Workspace-based Application Insights so if someone has used or know about pricing then please share a link here. Please share official/authenticated information ONLY.

Answer (score 2):

> workspace-based application insight pricing calculator

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cost-logs#application-insights-billing),

> Since [workspace-based Application Insights resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource)   store their data in a Log Analytics workspace, the billing for data ingestion and retention is done by the workspace where the Application Insights data is located. This enables you to leverage all options of the Log Analytics pricing model, including [commitment tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cost-logs#commitment-tiers)
> in addition to Pay-As-You-Go.

As per [Azure Monitor pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/monitor/)

- Application Insights charge for the data they consume.
- Two different types of logs can be ingested for ***workspace-based Application Insights*** data

1. **Analytics Logs** and
2. **Basic Logs**

- Application Insights data absorbed into either the workspace-based or classic versions is free to keep for 90 days without any price charges.

***References taken from***

- [Azure Monitor pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/monitor/)
- [Application insights billing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cost-logs#application-insights-billing)